# Hibernate OneToMany relation doesn't map new data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two entities Courses and CourseUser. Courses mapped with OneToMany annotation to a CourseUser. After i add a CourseUser in a list of CourseUsers in Course and update it, new row appears in table CourseUser but it doesn't mapped to a Courses. If i call toString of courseUsers list from courses after update it will be empty.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSES")
public class Courses{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private int course_id;

    @Column(name = "course_name", nullable = false)
    private String courseName;

    @Autowired
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<CourseUser> courseUsers = new HashSet<>(0);
```

CourseUser entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE_USERS",
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"course_name", "user_name"})})
public class CourseUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ev_id")
    private int ev_id;


    @Column(name = "course_name", nullable = false)
    private String courseName;

    @Column(name = "user_name", nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "course_role")
    private String courseRole;

    @Column(name = "grade")
    private int grade ;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Courses course;
```

this is how i add new courseUser to a course :

```
Courses course = courseDAO.getCourse(id);
Set<CourseUser> courseUsers = course.getCourseUsers();
CourseUser newUser = new CourseUser();
            newUser.setUserName(name);
            newUser.setCourseRole(role);
            newUser.setCourseName(course.getCourseName());
            courseUsers.add(newUser);
            course.setCourseUsers(courseUsers);
            update(course);
```

and here is CoursesDAO update method:

```
public void update(Courses course) {

        Session session = sf.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.merge(course);
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of initializing `Set<CourseUser> courseUsers = new HashSet<>(0)`?

Comment: i've done it like in this tutorial https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to save entity, which is referenced by id.
In your case, you have to save `CourseUser` at first, and then add it to `Course`.

For example:

```
Courses course = courseDAO.getCourse(id);
Set<CourseUser> courseUsers = course.getCourseUsers();
CourseUser newUser = new CourseUser();
newUser.setUserName(name);
newUser.setCourseRole(role);
newUser.setCourseName(course.getCourseName());
// this row is very important
// after thus operation newUser will have an id to be referenced
courseUserDto.save(newUser);
courseUsers.add(newUser);
course.setCourseUsers(courseUsers);
update(course);
```

---

Also, there is some redundant code that you wrote:

```
Set<CourseUser> courseUsers = course.getCourseUsers();
// ...
course.setCourseUsers(courseUsers);
```

`course` already stores reference to `courseUsers`.